# How to remap Emacs evil-mode toggle key from Ctrl-Z?

Tags: emacs, shortcut-keys

I'd like to remap the toggle key for [emacs evil mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil). From <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to something that won't confuse me like the CUA bindings (I'd like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, but I think that terms don't recognize that one).

In [this external thread](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode#toc14) is a discussion on trying to do this with Viper mode.

Once one is fairly used to using less, *Gmail*, and *Vimium*, the vim key bindings for browsing are nice to go easy on the hands when mostly reading files. Less hitting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> which helps the hands/wrists.

Answer (score 7):

No need to modify the source. Just customize "evil-toggle-key".

```
M-x customize-variable evil-toggle-key
```

You can also just set the variable using `setq`. Make sure you set that variable before emacs loads `evil`, since `evil` uses the variable's value when setting the keymaps up. For example, this is how it goes in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq evil-toggle-key "C-`")
(require 'evil)
```

:)

Comment: I think the OP should pick this for the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I can modify the source by changing this line, to use ctrl backtick:

evil-vars.el

```
(defcustom evil-toggle-key "C-`"
```

I'd rather have a way that doesn't modify the source to make it easier to upgrade later, but this should work. This hack definitely works.